# asObservable Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-database

Не смог найти информацию о том, в каком потоке работает метод `asObservable` в Realm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оно будет работать в том потоке, который вы укажете в аргументе метода `subscribeOn()`. Если конкретный поток не указан, то в том, в котором код вызван.

И это если вы используете синхронное получение данных от реалма.